# Inner text from selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to take the inner text from this markup:

```
<span ng-if="vm.totalRecords > 1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    Displaying results 1-25 of 17,430
</span>
```

Using this selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.Dashboard-section div.pure-u-1-1 span.ng-binding.ng-scope').innerText
```

It returns `undefined`. Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('span')[0].innerText);
```

```html
<span ng-if="vm.totalRecords > 1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Displaying results 1-25 of 17,430</span>
```

This will log the `innerText` as opposed to the other code due to two reasons:

1. Using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of results, hence why we use `[0]` to reference the first found element.
2. The actual query from your `querySelectorAll` couldn't find the HTML element. Simply using `span` as the query is enough.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` can be used to fetch the span elements and then select the first of them.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-if="vm.totalRecords > 1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Displaying results 1-25 of 17,430</span>
```