# CSS selector to output inner text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

- Not [CSS selector for elements containing certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)
- Not [CSS selector that gets information between two i tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849500/css-selector-or-xpath-that-gets-information-between-two-i-tags)

But just simply, is there CSS selector for ***output*** inner text?

E.g., for

```
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
```

I want to scrape/get/output `foo` and `bar`, the inner text, using CSS selector.

Using [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814440/inner-text-from-selector) it is

```
document.querySelectorAll('span')[0].innerText
```

But I want to use CSS selector only. Here is another example,

```
<h1 data-view-component="true" class="d-inline mr-3">v6.1.0</h1>
```

Is there a CSS selector to output inner text of `v6.1.0`, that https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andybalholm/cascadia might be able to support?

Comment: Maybe impossible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What would output inner text mean?

Comment: @AHaworth, I think he means something just like how we get and set  '.innerHTML' and '.textContent' in JavaScript

Comment: @xpt, if I had an idea of what you want to achieve with this, there might be another approach to it